# App store connect, add first in app purchase

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm sorry for asking this question once more.
I've found different replies but no one helped for me.

I'm trying to submit a brand new app to the app store but my app was rejected with the message:

> We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

I created my in-app purchase and the status of this purchase os "ready to upload".
As I understood, I should create a new app version to submit this purchase but I don't have a "plus" icon which creates a new version.

I uploaded with XCode a new version (1.0.2).
Consequently, the app version changed in the app store connect, but the dialogue which allows me to add my in-app purchase hasn't shown.

How can I create a new version?

Help me, please.
I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue.
The problem was with my in-app purchase.
I solved it by turning the content hosting off in the in-app purchase settings.